# JSON file update using jq (bash script)

Tags: json, jq

Need some help for change the value in JSON file using jq command.

**Error:**

```
[jenkins@devops-dev-02 New]$ jq 'map(if .Tags[11].Key == "Period" then .Tags[11].Value = "Weekly" else . end)' create_snapshot.json
jq: error (at create_snapshot.json:54): Cannot index string with string "Tags"
[jenkins@devops-dev-02 New]$
```

**JSON File:**

```json
{
   "DBSnapshotIdentifier":"snapshot-myrds-backup-1",
   "DBInstanceIdentifier":"myrds",
   "Tags":[
      {
         "Key":"Name",
         "Value":"snapshot-myrds-backup-1"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Application",
         "Value":"myapp"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Environment",
         "Value":"Dev and QA"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Period",
         "Value":"Daily"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `map()` doesn't make sense as the top-level call when your only item is a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `map()` over a dictionary, you operate on only its values, throwing the keys away. The value `"snapshot-myrds-backup-1"` has no `.Tags`, nor can you take item 11 of that nonexistent `Tags` entry.

---

What you want here is:

```
.Tags |= map(if .Key == "Period" then .Value = "Weekly" else . end)
```

`map()` is usually used to iterate over an array; for JSON objects, `map_values()` would usually be used to "map" over the object's values while retaining the keys, except for those whose values are mapped to `empty`.